# downloading ant for windows command line

Tags: java, apache, ant

I am trying to download and install the windows command line version of ant, but all the instructions seem to be for the eclipse plugin version.  I already have the ant eclipse plugin installed.

**Can someone show me how to download and install the command line version of ant for windows?**

I found [this download site](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/download.cgi).  I also found [these instructions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html).  But I can't seem to find a set of instructions that is matched by the contents of a download site.  The [git page for ant](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf) has so many downloads that it is not clear which one if any I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be downloaded [here](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi). Just find `zip` distribution on the page.

Manual, including installation procedure is [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/installlist.html)

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to simplify this.